# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

while trying to load data from sqldatabase to jqgrid, on debugging the code the error popups saying

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid" and does not load data into jqgrid.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#t1").jqGrid({
                url: '/Home/getorders',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype:'GET',
                height: 150,
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                colNames: ['id', 'invoicedate', 'name', 'note', 'tax', 'total'],
                colModel: [{ name: 'id', index: 'id' },
                    { name: 'invoicedate', index: 'invoicedate' },
                    { name: 'name', index: 'name' },
                    { name: 'note', index: 'note' },
                    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax' },
                    { name: 'total', index: 'total'}],
                viewrecords: true,
                pager: "#d1",
                caption: "Table Data"
            });
                        var ids = jQuery("#t1").jqGrid('getDataIDs');                                           
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
                jQuery("#t1").jqGrid('addRowData',ids[i]);
                                             // does not load data into table "#t1".//
        });                   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="t1">
    </table>
    <div id="d1">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: version of internetexplorer is IE9.